# БД не создает файл db из за этого у меня не работает телеграмм бот

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram-bot, sqlite

```
    def sql_start():
    global base, cur
    base = sq.connect('Bucket_buddy.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    if base:
        print('Data base connect OK!')
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS menu(img TEXT, name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT, price TEXT)')
    base.commit()


async def sql_add_command(state):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO menu VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', tuple(data.values()))
        base.commit()
async def sql_read(message):
    for ret in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM menu').fetchall():
        await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОбемь: {ret[2]}\nОписание: {ret[3]}\nЦена {ret[-1]}')
```

Comment: У Вас не создаётся Bucket_buddy.db?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('Bucket_buddy.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS menu(name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, img TEXT,  description TEXT, price TEXT)''')

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Так как у вас не указано, с какой базой вы работаете. То я решил дать вам пример с sqlite3
Единственное, что не очень я понимаю, почему у вас ЦЕНА должна формироваться как ТЕКСТ, а не как число с плавающей запятой

Comment: давайте я проверю за ранее спасибо большое!

Comment: https://youtu.be/m0ZRms4p7fc сделал как на этом видео

Answer (score 0):

Для одного соединения можно создать неограниченное количество cursor. Он также не является потокобезопасным. Модуль не позволяет делиться объектами cursor между потоками. Если это сделать, то будет ошибка.

Создавайте новый курсор в каждой функции где Вы работаете с базой и не забывайте его закрывать
Пример:

```
async def sql_add_command(state):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        cura = base.cursor()
        cura.execute('INSERT INTO menu VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', tuple(data.values()))
        base.commit()
        cura.close()
```

Ещё не забвыаем обрабатывать ошибки SQL try ... except